# Is an infinite dimensional closed ball topology?

Tags: general-topology

Does
$$
{\cal{G}}=\{g:D(g|f)\leq \epsilon\}
$$
with a distance measure, say,
$$
D(g|f)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ln \left(\frac{g(y)}{f(y)}\right)g(y)\mbox{d} y
$$
create a topological space? I am sorry if it is simple question. I would like to define the given closed ball under some well defined spaces.

Here $f$ and $g$ are some probability density functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like $f_i$ and $g_i$ are meant to represent functions.  What are the domains and codomains of these functions?  Why do they have a subscript $i$?  Is there some reason that the given integral exists?  You haven't successfully defined a topological space because you haven't been specific enough.

Comment: @Jim Belk sorry it was a fast post before leaving the office. I tried to edit. Please let me know if sth. is still missing.

Comment: I am sorry. I was at the outside and did the corrections from my mobile. I will be happy to hear your ideas..

Comment: The $D$ is not a metric... even where it exists.  If $g(y)>f(y)>0$ for all $y$, then $D(g|f) < 0$ for example.

Comment: @GEdgar yes $D$ is definitely not a metric. However it is positive definite. It is not negative for densities. If for all $y$, $g(y)>f(y)$ then one of them can not be density.

Comment: So, probability density functions may have the value zero, but do you want to allow that?

Comment: no both are positive definite. $g(y)>0$  and $f(y)>0$. Only when $y\rightarrow \infty=0$

Comment: @JimBelk I hope you re not protesting me since the first version of the question was not complete.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Sometimes I don't check this site very frequently.  I made a quick suggestion that you clarify your problem statement, and I was hoping that others would answer your question.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören That being said, I agree with GEdgar that $D$ does not seem like a metric, unless you have a specific reason to think that it might be.  Actually, I don't see offhand why it would satisfy any of the three metric properties.  For example, why would $D(g|f)$ and $D(f|g)$ be equal?

Comment: @JimBelk it is not a metric at all. Does it mean that if $D$ is not metric then $\mathcal{G}$ can not be a topology?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören First of all, I think you're confusing "topology" with "topological space".  The former is a collection of open sets, while the latter is the space together with the topology on the space.  Since $\mathcal{G}$ is clearly not a collection of open sets, you must be asking whether $\mathcal{G}$ is a topological space.  The answer is no -- it doesn't have a topology yet, but there are plenty of different topologies that could be put on $\mathcal{G}$, such as the discrete topology or any topology defined by a metric.

Comment: @JimBelk sorry for the late reply. Yes I think I am confused. Basically it was about the second answer given here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251532/is-this-set-compact he says "is not a compact set in the topology induced by this metric." So does it mean that it doesnt induce any topology and as long as I know compactness is defined over some subsets of topological spaces. Meanwhile $D$ is also not a metric. So in this case if I want to talk about compactness how should i formulate it?

Comment: @GEdgar thanks for your comments. You always try to let me think. There was another colleague of you, I guess his name was christian, he was also following some similar way))

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I've looked over some of your questions and I have a general comment.  You seem to be interested in proving that certain spaces of functions are compact, but you don't seem to be sure what topology you want to use on these spaces.  This is a common problem, and not an easy one.  Sometimes the solution is to find just the right metric or the right topology, and at other times the solution is to [compactify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_%28mathematics%29) your space by adding "boundary points" or "points at infinity".

Comment: (Continued)  There's not one uniform solution to this problem, and figuring out how to make a given space of functions compact often requires a careful examination of the structure of the function space.  The same thing holds true whenever you are defining a topology -- if you have specific goals in mind, you often must be quite careful about how your topology is defined.